# Remove indentation from the left of code in JetBrains editor

Tags: ide, indentation, jetbrains-ide

How can I remove indentation from the left of code in JetBrains editor?

[image]

I am using WebStorm. It is kind of an indentation in which I can not write anything.

Comment: Have you enabled Distraction Free mode in editor? (it's under `View` menu). If you exit it, such indentation will go away.

Comment: @LazyOne, I would like to use both Distraction Free mode and do not have the indentation. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. In such case you got the right ticket already. (in most cases people are just unaware of that mode / accidentally activated it so exiting that mode is a working solution that I had to mention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IDEA-148002](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002): it seems to be unresolved till now issue. ) :